# I am getting the following error : RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address

Tags: metamask, javascript, ethereumjs, mint, sendtransaction

I am getting the following error: RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.
It is a simple code to send transactions using a metamask chrome extension.

```
 <script>
   let accounts = [];
  const amountEth = 1
   const paymentAddress = '0x71C7656EC7ab88b098defB751B7401B5f6d8976F'
  const transactionParameters = { from: accounts[0], to: paymentAddress, value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether') };
  async function Mint(){
  ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_sendTransaction',  params: [transactionParameters] });

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring *accounts* as an empty array: thus accounts[0] will be null.
either declare it manually, or use [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html)